# insert timestamp in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert timestamp value in Oracle but its failing for the below query. Please suggest the fix for the same. I tried appending 'timestamp', but no luck.

```
insert into table (name, created_date) values ('test', '2023-04-24T11:11:11.807Z');
```

this is the exception I am getting:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the table definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'2023-04-24T11:11:11.807Z'` is not a `TIMESTAMP` data type, it is a string literal (that happens to look like a timestamp).

Oracle will try to be helpful and convert your string to the appropriate data type and this involves an implicit cast from string to `TIMESTAMP` (or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`) and your query is effectively:

```sql
insert into table (
  name,
  created_date
) values (
  'test', 
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    '2023-04-24T11:11:11.807Z',
    (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT')
  )
);
```

However, if the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` (or `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`) session parameter does not match the format of your string then you will get an exception.

What you need to do is either:

1. Use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

   ```sql
   insert into table (name, created_date)
   values ('test', TIMESTAMP '2023-04-24 11:11:11.807 UTC');
   ```
2. Use `TO_TIMESTAMP` with an explicit format model if you want to insert a `TIMESTAMP`:

   ```sql
   insert into table (name, created_date)
   values (
     'test',
     TO_TIMESTAMP( '2023-04-24T11:11:11.807Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"' )
   );
   ```
3. Use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` with an explicit format model if you want to insert a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

   ```sql
   insert into table (name, created_date)
   values (
     'test',
     TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( '2023-04-24T11:11:11.807Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZR' )
   );
   ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TcRuLQMD)

Answer (score 1):

Don't insert a string; it *might* work if your NLS settings match format model you used, but - if they don't, do it differently. For example, use `to_timestamp` function:

```
SQL> create table test (name varchar2(10), created_date timestamp);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('test',
  2    to_timestamp('2023-04-24T11:11:11.807Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

NAME       CREATED_DATE
---------- ----------------------------------------
test       24.04.23 11:11:11,807000

SQL>
```

---

On the other hand, `created_date` suggests that this column should get its value at time of insert or update, so perhaps you'd rather just insert `systimestamp`:

```
SQL> insert into test values ('test1', systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

NAME       CREATED_DATE
---------- ----------------------------------------
test       24.04.23 11:11:11,807000
test1      24.04.23 13:37:15,348647

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the conversion function to_timestamp with the appropriate format mask
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_TIMESTAMP.html#GUID-57E09334-E3CC-4CA2-809E-F0909458BCFA

And, generally, whenever you must have some conversions (like from char to date or timestamp), use conversion functions so as to avoid implicit conversions.